# Why does wx.Yield() not work?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am well aware/familiar how to handle [LongRunningTasks](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) in wxPython (using `threading.Thread` is just working fine). But I always wondered, why `wx.Yield()` and its siblings are not working (or how they shall be used properly).

Attached a (not so) minimal example, tested with `4.0.0a2 msw (phoenix)`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import wx

def long_running(handler):
    for i in range(10):
        thetxt = '{0}: {1}'.format(str(datetime.now()), str(i))
        sleep(1) # using this as drop-in for something which is blocking
        wx.SafeYield()
        wx.CallAfter(handler, thetxt)

class tst_frm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, 'Click to Status')
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)

    def on_btn(self, evt):
        the_txt = '{0}: EVT_BUTTON'.format(str(datetime.now()))
        self.update_prog(the_txt)

    def update_prog(self, update_txt):
        """Handler for task update (``str``)."""
        print(update_txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frm = tst_frm(None, -1, 'test_long')
    frm.Show()

    handler = frm

    long_running(handler.update_prog)

    app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT**: What happens:

- The `wx.CallAfter` events are processed
- The button events are registered but are being processed in the GUI only after `long_running` has completed

My questions:

- `wx.Yield` should allow to process events which are piling up?
- Can this example being made work with `wx.Yield` and if yes, how?
- If not, What is the explanation why it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The guys in [wxpython-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/q4YAOCPJ5_I) were able to answer the question. Two things were wrong:

1. `long_running` is started **before** `app.MainLoop()` has a chance to process events. Made sure now that `long_running` gets started **after** the MainLoop
2. `wx.Yield()` is the proper way to allow processing of the wx event loop

Modify to this makes it work:

```
def long_running(handler):
    for i in range(10):
        thetxt = '{0}: {1}'.format(str(datetime.now()), str(i))
        sleep(1) # using this as drop-in for something which is blocking
        wx.CallAfter(handler, thetxt)
        wx.Yield()

…

if __name__ == '__main__':
    …

    wx.CallLater(1500, long_running, handler.update_prog)

    app.MainLoop()
```